# How to decipher this code?

Tags: php, obfuscation

```
$o="QAAAOzh3b3cnYGJzWG9iZmNidQAgLy48Jzg5Cg0KDQGjbmlka3IAAGNiJy9TQkpXS0ZTQldGU08ABScpJyAoYGZra2J1fikEACADXIQABPFhaGhzBPU=";

eval(base64_decode("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"));

return;?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace `eval` by `echo` and run your script.

This gives (reformatted) :

```
$lll=0;
eval(base64_decode("JGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsPSdiYXNlNjRfZGVjb2RlJzs="));
$ll=0;
eval($lllllllllll("JGxsbGxsbGxsbGw9J29yZCc7"));
$llll=0;
$lllll=3;
eval($lllllllllll("JGw9JGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsKCRvKTs="));
$lllllll=0;
$llllll=($llllllllll($l[1])<<8)+$llllllllll($l[2]);
eval($lllllllllll("JGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbGw9J3N0cmxlbic7"));
$lllllllll=16;
$llllllll="";

for(;$lllll<$lllllllllllll($l);)
{
  if($lllllllll==0)
  {
    $llllll=($llllllllll($l[$lllll++])<<8);
    $llllll+=$llllllllll($l[$lllll++]);$lllllllll=16;
  }

  if($llllll&0x8000)
  {
    $lll=($llllllllll($l[$lllll++])<<4);
    $lll+=($llllllllll($l[$lllll])>>4);
    if($lll)
    {
      $ll=($llllllllll($l[$lllll++])&0x0f)+3;

      for($llll=0;$llll<$ll;$llll++)
        $llllllll[$lllllll+$llll]=$llllllll[$lllllll-$lll+$llll];

      $lllllll+=$ll;
    }
    else
    {
      $ll=($llllllllll($l[$lllll++])<<8);
      $ll+=$llllllllll($l[$lllll++])+16;
      for($llll=0;$llll<$ll;$llllllll[$lllllll+$llll++]=$llllllllll($l[$lllll]));

      $lllll++;$lllllll+=$ll;
    }
  }
  else
    $llllllll[$lllllll++]=$llllllllll($l[$lllll++]);

  $llllll<<=1;$lllllllll--;
}

eval($lllllllllll("JGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbD0nY2hyJzs="));
$lllll=0;
eval($lllllllllll("JGxsbGxsbGxsbD0iPyIuJGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbCg2Mik7"));
$llllllllll="";

for(;$lllll<$lllllll;)
{
  $llllllllll.=$llllllllllll($llllllll[$lllll++]^0x07);
}

eval($lllllllllll("JGxsbGxsbGxsbC49JGxsbGxsbGxsbGwuJGxsbGxsbGxsbGxsbCg2MCkuIj8iOw=="));
eval($lllllllll);

$lllllllllll='base64_decode';
$l=$lllllllllll($o);
$lllllllll.=$llllllllll.$llllllllllll(60)."?";$llllllllllll='chr';
```

Perform the `base64_decode` operation of the remaining strings, and you'll ahve the complete code.
Nice sample of obfuscated code, have fun with it!

Comment: it may be used in the subsequent encrypted code, so keep it. It may be that you'll have to make more echos instead of evals. This is a common way of obfuscation. AND do NOT run the script until you know what it does.

Answer (score 3):

That's what this code is evaluating:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/gallery.php'); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As this is part of a function (i guess it by "return" statement in the original code) this code makes nothing else but what stated above. I parsed it through step-by-step. Nicely encrypted code thou.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward: the alphabet soup is [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded PHP code, which is decoded via `base64_decode()` and run via `eval()`.

Looking at the decoded source code reveals that it's still highly obfuscated. Whoever that code is from *really* does not want you to decipher it. They probably have a reason for that.

Comment: That's my fav line: `$llllllll[$lllllll+$llll++]=$llllllllll($l[$lllll]))` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[this online decryptor](http://www.tareeinternet.com/scripts/decrypt.php)** for that or just replace `eval` keyword with `echo` because it is already getting decrypted using `base64_decode` function.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple, I had to do something similar.

1. instead of `eval(base64_decode(...));` do:

   $temp = base64_decode(...);
   print $temp;
2. See the last eval() in the printed string. Do a `substr()` to remove it, e.g.

   $temp = substr($temp, 0, -17);
3. Append a `print $lllllllll;` instead: `$temp=$temp."print $lllllllll;";`
4. Perform the eval(): `eval($temp);`

This will print out the code instead of evaluating it.

Code is:

```
$temp = base64_decode(...);
$temp = substr($temp, 0, -<your eval offset here>);
$temp=$temp."print $lllllllll;"
eval($temp);
```

Or the result directly :) :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/gallery.php'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```